# CocoaTouch : Localized Application Randomly Changing Language

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, localization, string

I have followed Apple's documentation on localizing iPhone software, using the genstrings ruby script to create my strings file, and have localized all of my nib files.  I also looked on both Apple's message boards, and around the net to try to find the solution.

I have made sure that all strings files are UTF-16, and changed my build setting 'Strings file output encoding' to UTF-16, but both in the simulator and on device, the localization keeps switching even though

```
NSArray* languages = [[NSBundle mainBundle] preferredLocalizations];
NSString* preferredLang = [languages objectAtIndex:0];
```

outputs the user-selected language correctly.  Is there something I am missing, or is this just a bug?

Comment: how is it switching?  does everything come out in the same language in a given run?  what code are you using to load localized strings?

Comment: I have two strings files, one in the folder de.lproj, the other is in en.lproj, in those folders is the Localizable.strings folder ( both the same name ( could be the problem )).

Inside of that folder is a file with the respective name, de and en.  Inside that file are the strings. the language is consistent during each run, it just arbitrarily picks one.  I am using NSLocalizedString(@"stringhandle",nil);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the folders from the project (delete reference only) and add the localizable.strings file from the en.lproj folder to the project (not the folder).Now right click the file click get info and add the localization that you want. Now you will see en and de in the localizable.strings file. Now run the project. Worked for me !!